# Help with rules - remove shipping option if coupon applied

Tags: commerce

I am in a situation where if a coupon code is applied to an order I'd like it to remove a free shipping option, if no coupon is applied then the allow the free shipping option.

I have a rule setup which has a condition to check if shipping address is in UK. I'd like to disable this rule if a coupon code 10off is added to the order but not sure how, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many Thanks
Max

Answer (score 1):

Check for shipping address and coupon code application in the same rule.
events: "After updating an existing commerce order".
conditions: your conditions
actions:
Condition IF -> "Coupon code for a particular discount has been added to the order"(Select your 10off discount from drop down list) -> "Remove all shipping line items from the order".
Condition ELSE -> "Apply shipping rate to an order".

Although your business logic may require a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this has definitely helped me! Although I think I'll need to modify that slightly as I don't want remove all shipping line items. I have rules in place that check if ship addr in uk + value under £15 apply one rule or if value over £15 apply another. So I need to figure out how to setup the rules/components for that. Thanks